# Foxpro Between Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foxpro

I am currently looking at foxpro queries, aka if SQL where drunk and I need help understanding how something works as I am completely new to foxpro.

```
SELECT keyfld, SUBSTR(CCB_SERIAL,11,2) AS a ;
FROM g:\mirror\DBFS\CCB ;
WHERE 
(BETWEEN({^2018-01-01},pl_st_dt, pl_end_dt) or 
BETWEEN({^2018-03-31},pl_st_dt,pl_end_dt))
```

My understanding of how to interpret the bottom 2 lines is

```
where
     pl_st_dt >= '2018-01-01' OR
     pl_end_dt >= '2018-01-01' OR
     pl_st_dt <= '2018-03-31' OR
     pl_end_dt <= '2018-03-31'
```

Is that correct?

I am trying to take a foxpro query and write the equivalent t-sql version.

Comment: Removed sql server and tsql tags as this has nothing to do with sql server....you stated this is foxpro.

Comment: Edited my post to explain why I had those tags in the first place.

Comment: Notice the use of parentheses in the original. So no - your tsql query is not the same. I would suggest that the original query might be logically flawed - but who can say without understanding the use/goal of such a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.

The BETWEEN there is equivalent to:

```
({^2018-01-01} BETWEEN pl_st_dt and pl_end_dt) or 
({^2018-03-31} BETWEEN pl_st_dt and pl_end_dt)
```

So your equivalency would be:

```
WHERE
  (pl_st_dt <= '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-01' <= pl_end_dt)
  OR
  (pl_st_dt <= '2018-03-31' AND '2018-03-31' <= pl_end_dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not talking to SQL Server, it will be faster to use the FoxPro explicit date format rather than a string. That is, {^2018-01-01} rather than '2018-01-01'.

Also less error-prone, because the string might be interpreted in different ways, depending on the FoxPro date settings.

Another thing to keep in mind is that FoxPro tables have both Date and Datetime data types. Date is integral (meaning exact comparisons are reliable), but IIRC, the latter has sub-millisecond resolution. Again IIRC, when comparing the two, FoxPro simply truncates a Datetime to a Date, so beware of unexpected results.